# How to display a clock with the current time in a Windows Core IoT app?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-10-universal

I am trying to create an Windows 10 IoT app running headless on a Raspberry Pi 2.
Everything is set up correctly and I am able to debug my from Visual Studio using the Raspberry Pi as the remote machine for debugging.

Now I want to add a clock on the app page but I can't figure out how to keep the displayed time updated. 
In plain old C# I would use a BackgroudWorker or something similar to keep the displayed time current, but that type is not available in UWP.

I have been looking into ["Create and register a background task"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299100.aspx) on MSDN but that seems to be way to complex, just to be able to keep the display time up to date.

So my question is: How can I - in the simplest posible way - create a clock display that is updated every time the time ticks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is running headless, you will have to set data to a display device (LCD, LEDs, etc.).
With a headed app, you will use a XAML page to display the clock.
You can use a timer to get notified every time span occurs.

Timer declaration

```
ThreadPoolTimer _clockTimer = null;
```

Timer initialization

```
_clockTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(_clockTimer_Tick, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
```

Timer tick event

```
private void _clockTimer_Tick(ThreadPoolTimer timer)
{
    //Update your display. Use a dispatcher if needed
}
```

ThreadPoolTimer reference documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer.aspx

Keep in mind that a Raspberry Pi does not have a battery to save the current time. Your board will have to sync through the Internet to update its date/time.